# flatMap function in scala

Tags: scala, flatmap

In the below two scenarios, I have flatMap function invoked on a list. In both the cases, the map portion of the flatMap function returns an array which has a iterator. In the first case, the code errors out where in the second case, it produces the expected result.

Scenario-1

```
val x = List("abc","cde")
x flatMap ( e => e.toArray)
<console>:13: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: Char]Array[B]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
       x flatMap ( e => e.toArray)
```

Scenario-2

```
val x = List("abc,def")
x flatMap ( e => e.split(",") )
res1: List[String] = List(abc, def) //Result
```

Can you please help why in the first case, it is not behaving as expected ?

Comment: Interesting. `flatMap()` won't flatten a `List[Array[Char]]` (scenario-1) but it _will_ flatten a `List[Array[String]]` (scenario-2). In both cases if you change `flatMap()` to `map()` and then add `.flatten` at the end, they both work.

Comment: @jwvh yes, that works correctly. I am bit puzzled in the above context.

Comment: I think the difference is that in scenario 1 you actually have a `Array[B]` where `B` is some yet-to-be-decided supertype of `Char` which in combination with the search for an implicit conversion from `Array` to `GenTraversableOnce` causes a type inference issue. By the way you can just call `List("abc", "cde").flatten`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the difference is that in scenario 1 you actually have a `Array[B]` where `B` is some yet-to-be-decided supertype of `Char`. Normally the compiler would look for an implicit conversion to `GenTraversableOnce` but because `B` is not yet known you run into a type inference issue / limitation.

You can help type inference by filling in `B`.

```
List("abc", "cde").flatMap(_.toArray[Char])
```

Or even better, you don't need `flatMap` in this case. Just call `flatten`.

```
List("abc", "cde").flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

It is worth keeping in mind that `Array` is not a proper Scala collection so compiler has to work harder to first convert it to something that fits with the rest of Scala collections

```
implicitly[Array[Char] <:< GenTraversableOnce[Char]] // error (Scala 2.12)
implicitly[Array[Char] <:< IterableOnce[Char]]       // error (Scala 2.13)
```

Hence because `flatMap` takes a function

```
String => GenTraversableOnce[Char]
```

but we are passing in

```
String => Array[Char]
```

the compiler first has to find an appropriate implicit conversion of `Array[Char]` to `GenTraversableOnce[Char]`. Namely this should be `wrapCharArray`

```
scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[String]("abc", "cde").flatMap[Char](((e: String) => scala.Predef.wrapCharArray(scala.Predef.augmentString(e).toArray[Char]((ClassTag.Char: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Char])))))
```

or shorter

```
List("abc", "cde").flatMap(e => wrapCharArray(augmentString(e).toArray))
```

however due to type inference reasons explained by Jasper-M, the compiler is unable to select `wrapCharArray` conversion. As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793684/5205022) puts it

> `Array` tries to be a Java `Array` and a Scala Collection at the same
>   time. It mostly succeeds, but fail at both for some corner cases.

Perhaps this is one of those corner cases. For these reasons it is best to avoid `Array` unless performance or compatibility reasons dictate it. Nevertheless another approach that seems to work in Scala 2.13 is to use `to(Collection)` method

```
List("abc","cde").flatMap(_.to(Array))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions, your type is wrong.

In the first case, if you appy map not flatmap, you obtain List[Array[Char]]. If you apply flatten to that, you get a List[Char]

In the second case, if you appy map not flatmap, you obtain List[Array[String]]. If you apply flatten to that, you get a List[String]

I suppose you need to transform String to Char in your Array, in order to make it work.

I use Scala 2.13 and still have the same error.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But even in my second case, the functional literal I supply to flatMap, produces an Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val x = List("abc","cde")
x: List[String] = List(abc, cde)

scala> x.flatMap[Char](_.toArray)
res0: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, c, d, e)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I just copy & paste your snippet in my Scala console. It gives error ( wrong number of type parameters for method flatMap ...) . I have Scala 2.12.8. Is this fixed in higher version of Scala ?

Comment: I run your code on my computer and I have 2.13. I updated my answer with what I get.